# DocuSign acquire user credentials C# SDK

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

We are using DocuSign (OAuth2 with scope: signature), we have problem in our integration tests as the refresh token expire after 30 days, so our tests will fail as the refresh token saved in credential.json file became invalid.
It there any method in docusign SDK we can call to launch browser on docusign login page, where we can enter docusign account credentials, and get back new token credentials, so we can update our credentials.json file programmatically ?

I am just asking for method name.

In gmail api we used GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() to solve this problem, so I am asking is there a class in docuSign SDK that do same functionality as this ?

[Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4xpS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. To regenerate the refresh token, the user would need to login again and generate a new authorisation code.

However, you can take advantage of the [extended scope](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/authorization-code-grant-refresh-tokens) to generate a new refresh token whenever you use the refresh token to generate an access token.

If you are, building a service integration that doesn't require the user to login frequently, you might also consider [JWT Authentication.](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use extended scope
2. Obtain a new refresh token (and access token) at least once every 30 days. No user presence is needed for this operation
3. Conclusion: you'll always have a usable refresh token.